# Using Beautifulsoup to find cell data, then print entire row if certain cell value is found

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Currently, I have a table that looks like this:

```
<tr class="tdc"><td class="myip_tdc"><a href="javascript:showIt('w115');">Account</a><br/><small>client</small></td>
<td class="tdc">Nov, 19 2015 05:18 pm </td>
<td class="tdc"><small><span style="color:green"> Check </span></small></td>
<tr class="tr"><td class="tde" colspan="6">
<div class="divl" id="wtt1266" style="display: block"><table><tr><td style="padding: 5px"><table><tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr><tr><td>
</td><td>
```

The cell containing the string "Check" is the one I want to look for. I assume it's looking for the exact string, so maybe I need regex to handle the fact that I do **not** want "checked" to also count. I haven't even gotten there yet, but if someone has insight to offer, I'll take it!

So, I have the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(nextpage, "lxml") #page is now converted to a BeautifulSoup object
table = soup.find("table", {'class':'tbled'}) #here is our table
tablerow = soup.find("tr", {'class':"tr"}) #here is a single row of that table
tablecell = soup.find("td", {'class':'tdc'})

for line in tablerow:
    if line.find("Check"):
        print "Yay"

print line
```

So, the problem with this is that it's printing all the cells (good), but printing "Yay" after every line. I just want it to print "Yay" after the single cell with "Check" in it. I thought the if statement would take care of that, but I've messed up that logic somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: try `if 'Check' in line:` instead since `line.find("Check")` will only be false if the strings starts with `Check` (since the index will be 0). `.find()` returns -1 if nothing is found, which evaluates to true

Comment: In my opinion, it will be more handy (and faster) if you use the lxml module instead of beautifulsoup and if you take the time to learn how to build an XPATH query. I don't think you need a regex here.

Comment: @RNar, "if 'Check' in line:' gets me no "yay" printouts, even though I can see it right there. Any ideas?

Comment: if you put the `print line` inside of the for loop, you will print everyline. do that to see for sure that you are grabbing the data you actually need when you set `tablerow`. I feel like you might not be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to go the regex route instead, this would be the regex

```
for line in tablerow:
     match = re.search("\bCheck\b", line)
     if match:
         print "Yay"
```

This would match Check but not Checked

Or if you dont want it to be case specific

```
for line in tablerow:
     match = re.search("\b.heck\b", line)
     if match:
         print "Yay"
```

Would also work

Comment: but what about `Sheck`?! (kidding) but I do suggest changing to `[Cc]` instead of `.`

Comment: haha I actually thought about that exact same word too. The reason why I used the "." instead of Cc was that it takes less steps to find a match on regex101 (albeit by only a few, but I like to try and find least steps possible and I figured sheck was a fairly low probability : p )

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to work. It won't print "yay" after it finds Check, even though I'm looking right at it...

Comment: use this code to figure out what the line is in tablerow......... print line ... put it right before the line .....  match = re.search("\bCheck\b", line)

Comment: I think you are going to want to use tablecell and not tablerow

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach the problem.

One idea would be to pass a [function as a `text` argument value](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to the `find()` method. That function would strip the text of an element and compare it to `Check`. Then, once the element found, we can go up in the tree and [find the parent](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent) `td` element:

```
elm = soup.find(text=lambda x: x and x.strip() == "Check")
td = elm.find_parent("td", class_="tdc")
```

To extend @Nefarii's answer, here is how you can apply the word-bounded regular expression:

```
elm = soup.find(text=re.compile(r"\b[Cc]heck\b"))
td = elm.find_parent("td", class_="tdc")
```

Comment: Hm, elm gives me "None" if I print it. 
 `for line in tablerow:
        elm = soup.find(text=lambda x: x and x.strip() == "Check")
        print elm`

Comment: @SamW I think you are looking into a wrong place - `tablerow` contains rows with `class="tr"` while the element having `Check` text is inside the `tr` with `class="tdc"`.